PowerPivot change Total % depending on date range that's selected
I have a table as per below:

My issue is with the Percentage of Weekly Hours. Obviously this will only be correct if the person using the workbook is selecting one whole week.
I want to know how I can go about it working depending on the date range that is selected on the Week Slicer?
I have all the staff FTE which is how the calculations are being worked out currently.
For example if I select 2 whole weeks from the slicer the contracted hours should show 80 and the percentage should adjust according to that.
The current PowerPivot calculations I am using for these three columns are:
TOTAL DURATION:=SUM(DATA[Duration])
WEEK HOURS:=MAX(DATA[WEEKLY HOURS])
PERCENTAGE OF WEEKLY HOURS:=[TOTAL DURATION]/[WEEK HOURS]
Im not sure if this is even possible but any ideas or thoughts would be perfect, im not an expert at this so if you could assist with the correct DAX equations when answering would help a great deal.
Would working it out per day 40 / 5 (working days in the week) = 8, so 8 hours per day would then be used to calculate the percentages ? Again not sure how I could do this to incorporate the date range selected.
thanks in advance ! Looking forward to hearing peoples ideas :)

For anyone interested I ended up creating a calculated measure using distinct count to see how many weeks where in the filtered data, to then times the contracted hours by this which then gave me the result I was after.
